# Updating $scope with firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Im trying to update the scope after I get the response from Firebase (I am doing it in the app controler part), here is a sample code.
PS I am using AngularFire ,Firebase and Angularjs
Thank You

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  app.factory("mealMacros", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
  var dbRef = firebase.database();
  var userId = sessionStorage.uid;
  var ordersRef = firebase.database().ref('user_info/' + userId + '/orders');
         return $firebaseArray(ordersRef);



  }
]);

app.controller("MealCtrl", ["$scope", "mealMacros",
  function($scope, mealMacros) {
  //  $scope.user = "Guest " + Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
//tried mealMacros.on.. didnt work 
  ordersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                var orders = snapshot.val();

                // Loop and parse order ids here
                for (var key in orders) {
                        var orderId = orders[key]['orderType'];
                       console.log(orderId);
                         $scope.products = orderId;
                    //code not reaching here 
                }

        });

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ordersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
     var orders = snapshot.val();
    // Loop and parse order ids here
    for (var key in orders) {
       var orderId = orders[key]['orderType'];
       console.log(orderId);
       $scope.products = orderId;
      //code not reaching here 
    }
  });
```

First you need to make sure you get data in `var orders`

Then `$scope.products = orderId;` you set the same variable in a loop. Maybe `$scope.products` is an array and you want to push data in it? `$scope.products.push(orderId);`

Finally, setting a `$scope` variable inside a .on event, you will need to call `$scope.$apply()` before the function returns.

```
  ordersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var orders = snapshot.val();
    console.log(orders); // make sure there's an array here
    for (var key in orders) {
       var orderId = orders[key]['orderType'];
       $scope.products.push(orderId);
    }
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

One last thing, `var orderId = orders[key]['orderType'];` may not work as expected depending on the structure of your `var orders` array.

You can try `var orderId = key.orderType;` if that doesn't work.

Comment: Worked Perfectly. This works though var orderId = orders[key]['orderType']; Anyway thank you alot!